# Grouping box plot based on time and coloring based on categories

Tags: r, boxplot

I am making a box plot for the data I have. Here is the data frame. I wrote the codes and got a nice box plot as in picture 1. But I suppose that there must be box plot for all (2,3,4) time for Land each. As (at 2 time step in first grid extremely saline there should be box plots for all type of land, so on and forth). I may be missing grouping them based on time please see the picture 2. I have also tried to group them but couldn't get the graph as I intended to do. Any help will appreciated. Thanks

```
Seed(123)
ID = 1:5
Time = rep (c(1,2,3,4,5), each = 20)
Type = 1:25
data <- data.frame( IDn = rep(ID,20), Time,  Land = rep(Type, 40), y = rnorm(100,0,1), x = runif(100,0,1))
data$Land= ifelse (data$Land > 15,"large farmers", ifelse(data$Land <=5, "small farmers", "medium-farmers"))
data<- data %>% mutate(xtype = case_when(x> 0.8~ 'Extremely Saline',
                                                      x > 0.6 & x<=0.8~  'Severely Saline',
                                                      x > 0.5 & x<=0.6~ 'Highly Saline',
                                                     x > 0.3 & x<=0.5~ 'Moderatley Saline',
                                                      x > 0.2 & x<=0.3~ 'Slightly Saline',
                                                      x <= 0.2~ 'Non saline' ))
## Box Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y =x)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = Land), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~xtype, nrow = 1) + theme_bw() 

#box plot grouping
ggplot(data, aes(x=Time, y =x, group=Time)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(color = Land), size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~xtype, nrow = 1) + theme_bw()
```

[image: Picture 1]

Picture 2
[image]

Edit: I tried suggested solution for my data set which i have used to put a reproducible example here. Data is some what large and got this graph time is overlapped. I am not sure what's happening.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for.
I changed the `aes` and made `Time` factor.

```
## Box Plot
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(Time), y =x, color = Land)) +
  geom_boxplot(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~xtype, nrow = 1) + theme_bw() 

#box plot grouping
ggplot(data, aes(x=factor(Time), y =x, group=Time, color = Land)) +
  geom_boxplot(size = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) +
  facet_wrap(~xtype, nrow = 1) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried solution for my data set. And got somewhat overlapped time. Can you please suggest? I have just edited question above– Sadaf 11 mins